# angular directly load a lazy module with nested router-outlet

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I have an Angular CLI application with several lazy loaded modules, some of which contain their own router-outlets. When navigating from the root of the application, I have no trouble accessing all routes. However, if I try to route directly to a route in a lazy loaded module, it appears that the browser tries to load the application from a folder which doesn't exist.

For Example, the root routing module has routes which look something like this:

```
{
            path: 'A', loadChildren:
            './A/A.module#AModule',
            canActivate: [LoadGuardService]
        }
```

AModule then has this for routes:

```
export const AModRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AHomeComponent, children: [
      { path: 'building', pathMatch: 'full', component: BuildingComponent },
      { path: 'sitewide', pathMatch: 'full', component: SitewideComponent },
      { path: 'spaces', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: '../spaces/spaces.module#SpacesModule' }
    ]
  }
];
```

If I load the application from scratch (running on port 4200), I can click through and navigate to `127.0.0.1:4200/A/building`, however I can't directly navigate to this same URL.

The console gives a bunch of errors like this:

`GET http://127.0.0.1:4200/es/inline.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED  building:20
.
.
.
GET http://127.0.0.1:4200/es/main.bundle.js 404 (Not Found) build:20`

I wonder if this is related to incorrectly setting the base href or something. I recently switched to the CLI and had to add
`{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }` to the root module providers to get it working.

Something more I found while writing this question:
Once I've navigated to, say, `A/building`, I can nvigate to `A/sitewide`, but not to `B/` or `A/spaces`. This was not an issue before switching to CLI

EDIT: Adding root router module (most of it, at least)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoadGuardService } from "./services/load-guard.service";

export const APPROUTES: Routes =
    [
        {
            path: 'A', loadChildren:
            './A/A.module#AModule',
            canActivate: [LoadGuardService]
        },
        {
            path: 'B', loadChildren:
            './B/B.module#BModule',
            canActivate: [LoadGuardService],
            data: { byPhone: false }
        },
...

    ];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(APPROUTES)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [LoadGuardService]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

To be clear, the ellipsis in the Routes array is not in the actual code. Just to shorten the snippet

Comment: Likely that LoadGuardService is returning false (does it rely on a service that a sub-component activates?), or maybe you're loading your RouterModule out of order or other routes somewhere else as well as lazily and there's a conflict?

Comment: I've tested by removing the LoadGuardService and stubbing it to always return true. I think if the LoadGuardService was returning false, the navigation would simply not happen, but instead it seems to be trying to load the application from A/building, which isn't a directory. I tried placing the AppRoutingModule first and last in the imports, with no change.

Comment: And in your app routing you are using `imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ]` and in your children you're using `imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]`? This is a weird one I never ran into, sorry I'm not more help.

Comment: Yes, I went through everything and verified I was using forChild everywhere but at the root. I think it's a weird one too. I've added more from the root router module. maybe the proper configuration changed since I initially wrote that?

Comment: The only two things I can think of that can be causing it with all this info is that you're exporting the const instead of just making it a straight declaration: `export const APPROUTES: Routes` -> `const APPROUTES: Routes` OR it has something to do with your child route having to go up one level `loadChildren: '../spaces/spaces.module#SpacesModule'` (only reason I think that is because I know there were some relative pathing issues in earlier angular cli, but that should be fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember at what point I had to add `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }` to app.module, but when I did that, I commented out `<base href="/">` in index.html (at the time, that seemed to work). I uncommented that line and everything's working now. Can someone explain what APP_BASE_HREF does?